Postgres: Combining rows which are identical in all columns but one
(Table where e.g. the 2nd and 3rd columns are identical except for the Consoles column)
I have a table of video games which has 6 columns: Game_Title, Consoles, ESRB_Rating, Content_Descriptors, Interactive_Elements and Content_Summary, all TYPE TEXT.
There are many rows where Game_Title, ESRB_Rating, Content_Descriptors, Interactive_Elements and Content_Summary are identical but Consoles is different.
I'm new to SQL, coming from pandas. A pseudocode description of the result I'm looking for would be:
If row1 is the same as row2 except for column Consoles:

      append the value of row2 Consoles to row1 Consoles, 
    
      Drop row 2

In the pictured Lego Star wars, you can see 7ish rows, aside from Consoles, 3 have the same data and 4 have the same data,  so we have 7 rows which can be combined into 2 rows where the consoles are all added into one row.
The following query kinda got what I was looking for:
SELECT Game_Title, string_agg(Consoles, ', ') AS Consoles, ESRB_Rating, Content_Descriptors, Interactive_Elements, Content_Summary
FROM  agames
GROUP BY Game_Title, ESRB_Rating, Content_Descriptors, Interactive_Elements, Content_Summary;

But the content summaries throw things off because they sometimes vary by 1 character. See if you can find it.
Anyway, the three questions I need asnswered are

How do I combine Consoles cells of rows where Game_Title, ESRB_Rating, Content_Descriptors, Interactive_Elements are the identical?
When I get that combined row, How do I get it to have a Content_Summary in the table? it could be from either row, because the two have *virtually the same summaries.
There are also rows in the picture which are full duplicates, How do I drop those?


If the GROUP BY fields are not identical rows will not be grouped.

Take a look at spacecraft vs spacecrafts

Ya, good catch, I'll edit the question

Please add the PostgreSQL version tag and table DDL. If there is a unique ID column, then removing the redundant rows can be accomplished by removing rows with IDs returned by (ARRAY_AGG(id ORDER BY id))[2:]. Besides removing the redundant columns, consider revising the model; e.g., add an ID column (if one does not exist) to agames and replace the cosoles column with a consoles table and a bridge table to capture the association between games and consoles. The current model is basically the equivalent of a text file. Consult a relational data modeling reference/tutorial.

Thanks, agames has an Id column but as of now every row has a unique ID do I wasn't sure how I could use it. Creating multiple tables sounds like a great idea for getting the ID working for me. Going to try that

Given a table, agames, with a unique id column and the columns mentioned in the original post, the following query groups by the specified columns, aggregates consoles into a comma separated list, deletes the redundant rows, and updates consoles to the aggregated lists:
WITH
  cte AS (
    SELECT MIN(id) AS kept_id,
           (ARRAY_AGG(id ORDER BY id)[2:] AS redundant_ids,
           STRING_AGG(consoles, ', ') AS consoles
    FROM agames
    GROUP BY game_title,
             esrb_rating,
             content_descriptors,
             interactive_elements,
             content_summary
  ),
  deleted_rows AS (
    DELETE FROM agames
      USING cte
      WHERE agames.id = ANY (cte.redundant_ids)
  )
UPDATE agames
  SET consoles = cte.consoles
  FROM cte
  WHERE agames.id = cte.kept_id;

